# Change selected content of a file using perl script

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I need help to write some Perl code to replace some selected values in text files. Below is the sample of my text files.

> server=host1
>
> ```
> network=true
> start=false
> end=YYYYMMDD
> key=34
> ```

change to

> server=host
>
> ```
> network=false
> start=true
> end=YYYYMMDD
> key=10
> ```

I want the value of start and network to generated randomly false or true.sometimes true sometimes false

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: There is a lot of context missing from your question... What is the purpose of this exercise? Why do it in Perl? And most importantly, [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: @thkala actully I need to run some system commands before and I want some randomly generated value {true/false} for the given fields as I need to pass random generated file as input for serveral cases

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -i.bak -lpe'
    for my $word (qw(network start)) { 
        s/$word=\K.*/rand > 0.5 ? "true" : "false"/e 
    }
' *.txt
```